# FindViewById on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need some way to find View/object by its ID. I heared about FindViewById function, but it's not present in my ContentPage class. Where can I find it?

Context: I have ListView with buttons inside. I don't know how many buttons are there. When user clicks on one of those buttons, I get its ID and store globally. What I want to accomplish is to find this specific button, which id was stored in variable.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="chooseObjectButtons">
      <ListView x:Name="SlotsList" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout>
                  <Button Text="{Binding Text}" BackgroundColor="Gray" Clicked="SlotChosen" />
                </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using Xaml?@Ludwik11

Comment: @AkashAmin yes I am. I'm generating listview of buttons. When user click button I get its id. Now I want to find this button using this saved id.

Comment: Use `x:Name` in xaml, you can directly reference it in your backend C#. @Ludwik11

Comment: But this ListView generates plenty of those buttons. How would I set unique name for each of them in XAML if I don't know how many of them will be displayed?

Comment: Why not tap event for listview item?https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/

Comment: As Akash stated, you should be doing something on a tap event and handle the item in that particular cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the XAML to:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Slots}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout>
               <Button Text="{Binding Title}" BackgroundColor="Gray" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" Command="{Binding Select}" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Handle click:

```cs
private Button LastButtonClicked;

void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (LastButtonClicked != null)
    {
        // Change background here
    }    
    LastButtonClicked = (Button)sender;
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

To process the specific command for each button use:

```cs
public List<SlotsButtons> Slots
{
    get
    {
        return new List<SlotsButtons>
        {
            new SlotsButtons
            {
                Title = "T1",
                Select = new Command(()=>{
                    // do stuff here when clicked.
                })
            },
            new SlotsButtons
            {
                Title = "T2",
                Select = new Command(()=>{
                    // do stuff here when clicked.
                })
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE: Initial question answer.**

In Xamarin Forms the class `ContentPage` is a `Partial class`.
One part is automatically generated from XAML and the other represents the code behind.
The XAML generated `Partial class` has the code to find the views by name.

The correct name is [FindByName](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Internals.INameScope.FindByName/p/System.String/) and you should't need to use this in your partial class because it its already made in the generated partial class.

If you want to access a view in your code behind just give it a name in XAML.
There is an XAML example:

```
<Button x:Name="button" ></Button>
```

And in your code behind you could do something like:

```
button.BorderWidth = 3;
```

If you still need to find a view for some reason, do this:

```
var button = this.FindByName<Button>("button");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't exactly told what I'm trying to do. As you can see in one of comments under the question "I'm generating listview of buttons. When user click button I get its id. Now I want to find this button using this saved id."

Comment: I can't set the name for each of buttons, because I don't know how many of them will be in listview.

Comment: But somewhere in the code you have to create the buttons. In that code Generate a name for it. If you're creating the buttons inside a for loop you could do something like new Button() {Name = "Button" + i};

Comment: How can I apply this incrementation in XAML? I mean: the same thing like you described but fully in XAML.